# If I use EF 4 to insert / update / Get by ID will the performance be worse?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1

I want to use Entity Framework 4 but without using complex linq queries only some very simple ones like get by id or `xField = value` or to insert and update.

Do you guys think the performance in this case will be near to the performance of `SqlCommand` ? Because there is really no overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the queries are simple selectds andget by ID, EF will, be slightly worse than SQLCommand, but minimal. The additional overhead will be unnoticeable.

Comment: that what I was thinking too , I am just using for simple operations (get by id , update ,insert ) while queries especially the complex ones are excuted in SP and retrieved as import function

Answer (score 1):

There is an overhead, really. :)

Regardless of the query complexity, Entity Framework have to translate query to SQL (well, more simple query translates faster), and to materialize query results (convert result of SQL command to entity objects), and track changes you making to objects.

EF team says, that they working for better performance... And the latest versions really works faster, but overhead still remains.

On the other hand, will this overhead be significant for your concrete task?

Also, look at this post: [Entity Framework 5.0 Performance Improvements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/14/sneak-preview-entity-framework-5-0-performance-improvements.aspx).

Comment: your answer was good too, but my case I really limited the use of EF to some simple operation without any LINQ to EF